# How to open android sdk 24 manager

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm on ubuntu 18.04.2.

I made apk file with keys, but google says that i need api version 28. I change api in buildozer.spec file, but it didn't change api, google still says it's 27. I change sdk to version 24 and set new path, but problem didn't go away.

Maybe i need to change something in sdk tools through manager, but i can't open it through ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-24/tools/ or ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-24/tools/ant/build.xml

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Myapp
# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.myapp

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav,wave,txt

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/prep.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/att.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 24

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path = ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-24/tools/ant/build.xml

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

...
```

buildozer logs:

```
wanheda@wanheda-VirtualBox:~/tr$ buildozer -v android release
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/wanheda/tr/bin
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Система управления пакетами Debian «dpkg», версия 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
Это свободное программное обеспечение. См. условия распространения в
Универсальной общественной лицензии GNU версии 2 или более поздней.
НИКАКИЕ гарантии не предоставляются.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/wanheda/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/wanheda/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Android NDK found at /home/wanheda/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 28
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27, 28)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 28 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/wanheda/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
[INFO]:    Found NDK revision 17.2.4988734
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /home/wanheda/.local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[WARNING]: Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, six, pyjnius, android, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
# Build the application #53
# Copy application source from /home/wanheda/tr
# Create directory /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/bbgn.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/sun320.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/empty.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/ob29.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/st30.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/semt.wav
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/att.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/obvodk.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/gori4.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/sun3222.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/slovar.py
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/w.txt
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/obvodk555.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/sun3334.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/obvodk33.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/ex1.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/bbgb.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/prep.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/blockscreen.kv
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/openscreen.kv
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/main.py
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/main.kv
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/settingsscreen.kv
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/hist1.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/musc3.wav
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/AGEMT200.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/nas1.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/nicknames.txt
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/bbgz.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/numbers.txt
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/obvodk333.png
# Copy /home/wanheda/tr/stt1.png
# Package the application
# project.properties updated
# Gradle project detected, copy files /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/src/main/java
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name Myapp --version 0.1 --package org.myapp.myapp --android_api 28 --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app --presplash /home/wanheda/tr/./prep.png --icon /home/wanheda/tr/./att.png --orientation portrait --window --release --sign --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Getting Android API version from user argument: 28
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27, 28)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 28 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/wanheda/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
[INFO]:    Found NDK revision 17.2.4988734
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /home/wanheda/.local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
[WARNING]: Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, six, pyjnius, android, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, six, pyjnius, android, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp
Listing '/tmp/p4a-extra-env-Eb81R5'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'...
Compiling '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...
Compiling '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
Compiling '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/app/slovar.py'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/modules'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/android'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src/org'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/src/org/jnius'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/audio'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/camera'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/gl'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/image'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/spelling'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/text'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/video'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/window'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/fonts'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/glsl'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/images'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/keyboards'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/deps'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/effects'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/extras'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/garden'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/cgl_backend'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/include'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input/postproc'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/input/providers'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lang'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib/vidcore_lite'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/modules'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/network'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/storage'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/gles_compat'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/highlight'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/packaging'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/pep8checker'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/theming'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors'...
Listing '/home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/uix/recycleview'...
[INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 29.0.0
[INFO]:        Building with gradle, as gradle executable is present
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleRelease
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    > Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
[DEBUG]:    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[DEBUG]:    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 28s
[DEBUG]:    28 actionable tasks: 27 executed, 1 up-to-date

[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    # Copying APK to current directory
[INFO]:    # APK filename not found in build output. Guessing...
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/release/myapp-release.apk
[INFO]:    # Add version number to APK
[INFO]:    # APK renamed to myapp-0.1-release.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/wanheda/tr/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/release/myapp-release.apk myapp-0.1-release.apk
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Android packaging done!
# APK myapp-0.1-release.apk available in the bin directory
wanheda@wanheda-VirtualBox:~/tr$
```

How i could solve my prolem?

Comment: Are you getting error messages? How does google tell you about the API?

Comment: Only warning: "Config token app android.sdk is deprecated and ignored, but you set value 24". And another one: "Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed"

Comment: As far as running the sdkmanager, you may need to install `Android Studio` (it's free), and run `Tools->SDK Manager`.